# Question on the $i\epsilon$ prescription

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, integration

I am computing an amplitude in the Minkowski signature and after performing dimensional regularization (dim-reg), contracting a lot of indices, and simplifying into a few momentum integrals to expand I am left with evaluating the momentum integrals. However, I have been working in the Minkowski signature and thus my $\Delta$ in my $~1/(p^2 - \Delta)^2$ integral is of the following form $\Delta = q^2(1-x)x + m^2 + i\delta$. Now when I perform the $\epsilon$-expansion for my momentum integral, for example, the expansion of equation A.57 in Peskin & Schroeder, I get the following result
\begin{equation}
\frac{3\Delta^2i}{8\pi^2\epsilon} + \frac{\Delta^2i\left(3\log(1/\Delta) - 3\gamma + 2 + 3\log(\pi) + \log(64)\right)}{16\pi^2} + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^1)
\end{equation}
(the expansion was done in Mathematica).

Now my concern is when I plug in what I have for $\Delta$ and keep only terms of order $\epsilon^0$, I am going to have a lot of $i$'s running around. But, were the formulas as defined in appendix A of Peskin & Schroeder with or without the $i\delta$ prescription (where in P&S they use $i\epsilon$ instead which can be confusing so I changed it to $i\delta$). *If* this is the case then great, I'll just drop the $i\delta$ from my $\Delta$ and proceed to simplify.

But if not, then throughout my calculation will I have to back-track and replace all of my loop momentum products, for example if I was using $l^\mu$, $l^2$ with $-l_E^2$ as told to in A.43 of P&S? And something I would want to clarify on this point is then the question of whether or not I would have to also replace the product of $l^\mu k_{i,\mu}$ where $k_{i,\mu}$ is the momentum of an external particle with a negative as well or just the square of the loop momentum?

Staying on this point, if I did have to replace $l^2\rightarrow -l^2_E$ wouldn't this technically only change the sign on equation on A.45 and not A.47?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: $\uparrow$ A.57??